# PrimeNg p-menu image with style

Tags: angular, menu, primeng, menuitem

We have requirement to show user profile pic and name below that in menu. I am using Angular 12, **p-menu** from PrimeNg which allows you to specify html as label using **escape:false**

(PrimeNg Reference : https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menumodel)

```
<p-menu #menu [model]="userMenu" [popup]="true"></p-menu>
```

[image]

It is showing image and content but styling is not getting picked up.

Tried:

1. Style tag
2. Class tag
3. Specify Id but not picked

**Actual Output**:

[image]

**Expected Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Worked for me** :

```
<p-menu #menu styleClass="user-menu" [model]="userMenu" [popup]="true"></p-menu>
```

CSS:

[image]